# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck at buffer i/o error on dev sdb1, logical block 36, async page read and bluetooth hci0 unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 20.04 dual-booted with windows 10 on a device with a HDD and SSD. The root of ubuntu is on the SSD partition and the home is on the HDD partition.

Although Windows 10 operates properly, Ubuntu shows this screen every time I tried to boot it and gets stuck at it.

[image: see the image here]

Note that the partition `sdb1` where the buffer i/o err occurs belongs to Windows.

This occurred after I tried to boot onto Ubuntu after executing the commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: someone told me to boot into windows then do a restart as windows releases all its locks on partitions on restart, I did so and get this screen for first time [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1daT7hjhC0CaKBXSfbEVDCNhPKjRyrSk5/view) but when i did this another time, i got the same screen in the post